# Divrei Talmud (Rav Avrohom Eliyahu ben Avrohom Eliyahu Kaplan)

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I read (in the book of collected writings of Rav Avrohom Eliyahu ben Avrohom Eliyahu Kaplan entitled B'ikvos Hayirah) that an additional publication was underway at the time of publication (~1960) to include original insights into the Talmud that Rabbi Kaplan discussed during his short life.

Is this publication now available in print, and if so where ?(It is available online [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1590522331050&pagenum=1&book=12970))

Comment: Bezras Bori--bounty!

Comment: Who was Rav Avrohom Eliyahu ben Avrohom Eliyahu Kaplan? I.e. who were his father and grandfather?

Comment: @GRAPKE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Eliyahu_Kaplan

Comment: Thanks. A fiery soul.

Comment: Is this a reference to Divrei Talmud?

Comment: @Harel13 Unsure what you mean... (see title)

Comment: I'm also unsure of what you mean. You said you read it in Be'ikvot Hayir'ah and linked Divrei Talmud pt. 1. Could it be a reference to pt. 2 which came out after BH?

Comment: @Harel13 I meant to indicate that although the volumes are available online, I am in search of a physical volume

Comment: I feel this is the type of thing you can pick up in one of the backstreet Meah Shearim used bookstores